# java - 2D arrays issue

Tags: java

I have a problem with 2d array. I want to print 20 lines with a..j letters on each line. I can't print row 9, 19, 20 with following code.  Also, my code  prints 19x9 lines of NULL. Any ideas?! Thanks. That's my code:

```
public class cinema_seats {
    String[][] seats = new String[20][10];  

    for(int row=0; row<seats.length-1; row++){
        for(int column=0; column<seats[row].length-1; column++){

            if(row!=0)
                System.out.print("row" + row + " " + 'a' + " " + 'b' + " " + 'c' + " " + 'd' + " " + 'e' + " " + 'f' + " " + 'g' + " " + 'h' + " " + 'i' + " " +'j' + "\n")                     
            else            
                System.out.println();
                row++;                  
        }
        System.out.println();           
    }       
    for(int row=0; row<seats.length-1; row++){
        for(int column=0; column<seats[row].length-1; column++){                
            System.out.print(seats[row+1][column]);]        
        }
        System.out.println();           
    }               
}//main     
}//class
```

Comment: Please post your actual code.  What you have here will not compile.

Comment: You're incrementing `row` twice. You have the `row++` in the row `for` loop and in the body of the column `for` loop. Not sure if that's what you wanted? You will reach the end of the rows in the columns before the rows are finished with it like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue is that you're using `length-1`.

It should be like this:

```
for(int row=0; row < seats.length; row++){
    for(int column=0; column <s eats[row].length; column++){
```

...or like this:

```
for(int row=0; row <= seats.length-1; row++){
    for(int column=0; column <= seats[row].length-1; column++){
```

Plus you never intialized `seats[][]` with any value. That's why `null` is being printed.

I just fixed all the compile errors (there were a lot), and here is some code that at least runs, and also populates the `seats` matrix;

Also, if you want to print out "row 1" through "row 20", just add one when specifying the row number, since arrays are zero based.  An array of size 20 is indexed 0 through 19;

Edit:  After your comment, I think this is close to what you want:

```
public class cinema_seats {
  public static void main(String[] args){

    String[][] seats = new String[20][10];  

      String seat = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

      for(int row=0; row<seats.length; row++){
          for(int column=0; column<seats[row].length; column++){    
            seats[row][column] = new String (Character.toString(seat.charAt(column))); 
          }
      }

      for(int row=0; row<seats.length; row++){
          System.out.print("row: " + (row + 1) + " ");
          for(int column=0; column<seats[row].length; column++){                
              System.out.print(seats[row][column] + " ");        
          }
          System.out.println();           
      }
  }

}//main
```

Output:

```
row: 1 a b c d e f g h i j 
row: 2 a b c d e f g h i j 
row: 3 a b c d e f g h i j 
row: 4 a b c d e f g h i j 
row: 5 a b c d e f g h i j 
row: 6 a b c d e f g h i j 
row: 7 a b c d e f g h i j 
row: 8 a b c d e f g h i j 
row: 9 a b c d e f g h i j 
row: 10 a b c d e f g h i j 
row: 11 a b c d e f g h i j 
row: 12 a b c d e f g h i j 
row: 13 a b c d e f g h i j 
row: 14 a b c d e f g h i j 
row: 15 a b c d e f g h i j 
row: 16 a b c d e f g h i j 
row: 17 a b c d e f g h i j 
row: 18 a b c d e f g h i j 
row: 19 a b c d e f g h i j 
row: 20 a b c d e f g h i j
```

Comment: Hi.Thank you guys.I want to print seats for a cinema like this row1 a b c d e f g h i j / row2 a b ....j / row3 a b ...j  and so on .I want to print 20 rows, each row with letters from a to j.

Comment: Hi Daniel,Thank you very much. Works